# How to import a dll(make a link to dll) so that the link refers to the program folder?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making a link to the folder with dlls in VS, but on the other PC the program doesn't seem to work appropriately.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work appropriately" it not a helpful diagnostic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're copying your output executable folder to another machine and it is failing.

My guess is that you are not copying the DLLson build. 
Two methods of attempting a fix:

- Select each .dll and open the properties window, it will have an
  option: "Copy to Local." Set that to true
- Open the properties on the
  project and go to the References tab. There you will see all the DLLs
  referenced in the project. Set the DLLs in the folder you specified to have True for the "Copy to Local" option.